# HQL like operator for case insensitive search

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sql-like

I am implementing an autocomplete functionality using Jquery, when I type the name, it fetches the record from the db, The records stored in db are mixture of capital & small letters. I have written a HQL Query which fetches me the records with case-sensitive, but I need to records irrespective of case. Here is the query,

```
List<OrganizationTB> resultList = null;
Query query = session.createQuery("from DataOrganization dataOrg where dataOrg.poolName   
like '%"+ poolName +"%'");
resultList =  query.list();
```

Ex : If I have pool names, HRMS Data set, Hrms Data, Hr data etc... if I type HR or hr I need to get all the 3 records, which I'm not able to.

Please help...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

change your query to

```
"from DataOrganization dataOrg where lower(dataOrg.poolName)   
like lower('%"+ poolName +"%')"
```

for more information have a look 14.3 [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Don't you think that `poolName.toLowerCase()` is a good choice over  `lower('%"+ poolName +"%')"` for like expression, as it prevents extra overhead for HQL function conversion to DB specific function?

Comment: @ArunKumar i think if you `poolName.toLowerCase()` then comparsion will be done at Java-Pojo, there will not be any SQL optimization where as in case of function `lower` there is possibility at dialect level to have SQL optimization and will consume less memory with less no. of objects fetched from database.

Answer (score 16):

A good solution is:

```
List<OrganizationTB> resultList = null;
Query query = session.createQuery("from DataOrganization dataOrg where lower(dataOrg.poolName) like lower(:poolName)");
query.setParameter("poolName", '%'+poolName+'%', StringType.INSTANCE);
resultList =  query.list();
```

So you protect your code from SQL injection

Comment: And you have table fields content and query string both lower-cased.

Comment: It would be cleaner if you let just one layer to do lowercase work. You have left side lowercased by HQL and right side lowercased by Java.

Comment: @horvoje you are right.  I edited.