# Hw to apply ignore case in JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am fetching the group name from entity but now i want to apply ignoreCase in the query, How can i do it? so i can fetch all groups without case sensitive.

```
SELECT g.* FROM GroupEntity g LEFT JOIN xNodeEntity node ON g.id = node.id WHERE (  (  (g.name LIKE '%Group%') )  )
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HQL like operator for case insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266229/hql-like-operator-for-case-insensitive-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the UPPER or LOWER function:

```
SELECT g.* FROM GroupEntity g LEFT JOIN xNodeEntity node ON g.id = node.id 
WHERE (  (  (UPPER(g.name) LIKE UPPER('%Group%')) )  )
```

But your query looks like SQL. Did you want to write JPQL?

Comment: using this query in namedNativeQuery